# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Sessions_Halls_HallId' on table 'Sessions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, schema

I want to create such DB([watch diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMO2R.jpg)), but I have an error when I try to add table "Sessions":

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Sessions_Halls_HallId' on table 'Sessions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I dont understand where are cycles or multiple cascade paths in schemas?

Comment: The error is self explanatory... what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried doing this? "Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints"

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMO2R.jpg) there is 2 cycles :

- loop 1 : Company / User / Areas / Company
- loop 2 : Company / Areas /  Cinema / Halls / Sessions / Films / Company

Review your data model to avoid cycles...

As an example, if companies have areas and user too you can says that areas of user is by Company... so there is no need to have a relationship between user and areas... !

Comment: about 1-st loop: I have 3 types of users: companyAdmin, areaAdmin, worker. As you can understand from the name of the roles companyAdmin can manage all tables that have ComapanyId as FK and areaAdmin can manage all tables that areaId as FK. I did not find any other way out, as now I understand using "cycle". Could you tell me what kind of connections can be made between the tables to remove the first cycle?

Comment: So you need to model an inherited entity that point to a ref user as : entity users + entity companyAdmins, areaAdmins, workers that have inherit from user